# Formulario no envía datos Android Studio GET

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json

Hola amigos estoy en un lio por que no puedo hacer que me envié los datos ni por post o get no se si estoy en algún error agradecería una ayuda.

```
public class SendMsgActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  CheckBox terms;
  EditText name,phone,email,msg;
  Button msg_send;
  ProgressDialog progressDialog;
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_msg);
    terms=findViewById(R.id.terms);
    name=findViewById(R.id.name);
    phone=findViewById(R.id.phone);
    email=findViewById(R.id.email);
    msg=findViewById(R.id.msg);
    msg_send=findViewById(R.id.msg_sent);
    msg_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ValidateAndSend();
        }
    });
    terms.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (terms.isChecked()){
                startActivity(new Intent(SendMsgActivity.this,TermsActivity.class));
            }
        }
    });
    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("abc",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

private void ValidateAndSend() {
    if (name.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

    }
    else if (email.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

    }else if (phone.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

    }
    else if (msg.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

    }else if (!terms.isChecked()){

    }
    else {
        String name,email,phone,msg;
        name= this.name.getText().toString();
        email=this.email.getText().toString();
        phone=this.phone.getText().toString();
        msg=this.msg.getText().toString();
        String url = sharedPreferences.getString(Api.url_post_form,"");
        if (url.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        if (isNetworkaAvailable()){
            new SendMsg().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,name,email,phone,msg,url);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Internet is not Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

public boolean isNetworkaAvailable() {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        return false;
    }

}


@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class SendMsg extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        URL url;
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            String name="", email="", msg="",phone="";
            try {
                name= URLEncoder.encode(strings[0],"utf-8");
                email= URLEncoder.encode(strings[1],"utf-8");
                msg= URLEncoder.encode(strings[3],"utf-8");
                phone= URLEncoder.encode(strings[2],"utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String queryString = "https://dominio.com/send.php"+"?contact_name="+name+"&contact_email="+email+"&contact_phone="+phone+"&message="+msg;
            url = new URL(queryString);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            /*con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("contact_name",strings[0]);
            jsonObject.put("contact_email",strings[1]);
            jsonObject.put("message",strings[3]);
            jsonObject.put("contact_phone",strings[2]);*/

            con.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.connect();


            //"date1":"2018-05-02 02:15:10.777"



            /*OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());

            Log.i("Response", jsonObject.toString());
            writer.write(jsonObject.toString());

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();*/

            Log.i("Response", con.getResponseCode() + " " + con.getResponseMessage());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Response", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(SendMsgActivity.this,"Be patient","Data is uploading",true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (progressDialog!=null){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (s!=null) {
            Log.i("Response", s);
            Toast.makeText(SendMsgActivity.this,"Message saved successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        else {
            Log.i("Response","No Data");
            Toast.makeText(SendMsgActivity.this,"Internet is not Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hay varias cosas que no estan bien escritas en tu codigo por ejemplo los Elementos del Layout al definirlos no realizas el casting(Editex) por ejemplo
deberia de ser asi.

```
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    msg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
```

En cuanto al AsyncTask no cuenta con una funcion definida llamada executeOnExecutor,puedes utilizar execute() en su reemplazo.

Eh realizado una prueba y me funcionado mas abajo el codigo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText name,phone,email,msg;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    msg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
    msg_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    msg_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new SendMsg().execute(name.getText().toString(),email.getText().toString(),phone.getText().toString(),msg.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
    private class SendMsg extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        URL url;
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            String name="", email="", msg="",phone="";
            try {
                System.out.println("Compuebo si recibo el parametro name:"+strings[0]);
                System.out.println("Compuebo si recibo el parametro email:"+strings[1]);
                System.out.println("Compuebo si recibo el parametro msg:"+strings[3]);
                System.out.println("Compuebo si recibo el parametro phone:"+strings[2]);

                name= URLEncoder.encode(strings[0],"utf-8");
                email= URLEncoder.encode(strings[1],"utf-8");
                msg= URLEncoder.encode(strings[3],"utf-8");
                phone= URLEncoder.encode(strings[2],"utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String queryString = "http://MyUrl";
            url = new URL(queryString);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        /*con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("contact_name",strings[0]);
        jsonObject.put("contact_email",strings[1]);
        jsonObject.put("message",strings[3]);
        jsonObject.put("contact_phone",strings[2]);*/

            con.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.connect();


            //"date1":"2018-05-02 02:15:10.777"



        /*OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());

        Log.i("Response", jsonObject.toString());
        writer.write(jsonObject.toString());

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();*/

            Log.i("Response:", con.getResponseCode() + " " + con.getResponseMessage());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            Log.i("Response:", sb.toString());
            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Response:", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        System.out.println("onPostExecute");
    }
```

El resultado en log:

```
 09-21 01:45:10.970 4281-5120/py.com.example.example.myapplication I/Response:: 200 OK
 09-21 01:45:11.008 4281-5120/py.com.example.example.myapplication ::<html>
```

Comment: Hola voy a revisar y te aviso